# Reading a value from site collection list inside my workflow

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, development, designer-workflow

I have created a site template which have a workflow inside it.and inside the template there is a workflow, now i need the workflow to be dynamic in a way that can work with newly added sites. the workflow will populate a fields named formattedID to be equal = **set of characters (ABC in the below picture) + the system generated ID** as follow:-

[image]

now i will create a list inside the site collection , where users will enter the site URL (or site name) , and the set of characters to be read by the workflow. then the workflow will read set of characters from the site collection list that is associated with the current site name or site URL. so can anyone adivce if this is possible to be achieved ?